# count categories of values

Tags: sql, if-statement, count, distinct

I have `int` values `v >= 0` in nullable column and I would like to count number of occurrences of Null, 0, 1 and 2+ in column how to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `group by`:

```
select (case when col in (0, 1) then cast(col as varchar(255))
             else '2+'
        end) as grp, count(*)
from t
group by (case when col in (0, 1) then cast(col as varchar(255))
               else '2+'
          end)
order by min(col);
```

The exact syntax for the `cast()` might depend on the database.  This also assumes all values are non-negative.

You can put the counts in different columns as well:

```
select sum(case when val = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_0,
       sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_1,
       sum(case when val >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2pl
from t;
```

Comment: `sum(case when val is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_null` was missing